# Why can I do ssh to my server using any private key?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I have Public key authentication enabled for connection to my server, after connecting to my server using my correct private key I can authenticate to my server using any private key file and it works.

I use `-i` option for specifying the private key:
`ssh -i /anything meliwex@server_ip`

Even if the file doesn't exist I can still connect to my server.
[image: Connection]

Is it possible that ssh caches the private key? If yes how can I remove that cache?

Comment: **Not `ssh` itself, but OpenSSH provides a program `ssh-agent`** that normally runs as a separate (per-user) process and remembers all keys you have used since login, until you explicitly remove it/them or kill the process; see the manpage for `ssh-add` which is the CLI. Some _other_ programs, notably GnuPG and many Linux desktops, provide other programs which mimic the same API and add other functionality (e.g. GnuPG's `gpg-agent` handles both keys for SSH and for email in the same process). `ssh-add -l` (lower ell) should show you the status of any of them.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sorry, I cannot delete now this post because of  the answers, but I will keep in mind that I will post these kind of questions not in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `-v` to see which keys are really used.

The `-i` option isn't exclusive, `ssh` is still able to use keys from a ssh-agent and also the default keys from `.ssh/id_*`

Probably your key in `.ssh/id_rsa` isn't protected with a passphrase.
Therefore ssh will use it silently and you can login.